# Changing WooCommerce Variation Selects to Radio Inputs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to change the selects in a variable subscription to radio inputs with labels. I've been able to modify the variable-subscription.php in order to achieve this but the problem now is the form's checkout button remains disabled, giving an error of: "Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart".

My best guess is this is due to the add-to-cart-variation.js no longer working since that JS is looking for .variations select. My questions are:

1. Am I correct in believing this JS file is the problem that needs to be udpated?
2. Should I even be editing that JS?
3. Are there other PHP/JS files that I need to be concerned with updating in order to convert my selects to radio inputs?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There used to be a plugin for this, but I think it fell out of date. 1. yes 2. no, never edit core files, you need to build your own plugin. 3. probably the PHP template that outputs the values.

Comment: I ended up using the WC Variations Radio Buttons plugin and it's working well. Thank you!